# How to sync up data in a SharePoint list item with TFS work item?

Tags: tfs

I have a SharePoint list which the user enter his incident information including system, severity, type, title, and description etc. How can I sync this SharePoint list information to populate a TFS workitem AUTOMATICALLY? Any help is greatly appreciated. A link to some tutorial or step by step instruction would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Event receive and simply use the code to make an entry to TFS.
Below URLs might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324161/insert-work-item-into-tfs-using-tfs-api

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ff5415e-0ef2-4c65-b0b7-a109187adf51/create-work-item-in-team-project-tfs-using-c-code?forum=tfsgeneral